# Detecting windows time changes by the user

Tags: c++, windows, date, settings

Is it possible to detect a change made by the user to windows date/time settings?
for example, if the user has changed the date from 23.5.2012 to 16.5.2012?
Are these changes registered somewhere?
I'll need to use a native API if there is one...

Answer (score 1):

See the [SystemEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) class. The SystemEvents class provides the ability to respond to specific types of system events. You can subscribe to the [TimeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx) event.

Comment: I was hoping there some native API... :)

Comment: It's just a wrapper for the WM_TIMECHANGE message.